# I want to make a SQL query into a python dictionary

Tags: python

The SQL result is as follows.

```
c.execute('select from_node_id, to_node_id, link_length  from link order by from_node_id')
== sql result
A, B, 10
A, C, 10
B, C, 5
B, D, 10
```

I want to express the SQL result like the Python code below.

```
graph["A"] = {}
graph["A"]["B"] = 10
graph["A"]["C"] = 10
graph["B"] = {}
graph["B"]["C"] = 5
graph["B"]["D"] = 10

infinity = float("inf")
costs = {} 
costs["A"] = infinity
costs["B"] = infinity

parents = {} 
parents["A"] = None
parents["B"] = None
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?